# WebRTC stop local tracks not disabling webcam after using replaceTrack

Tags: webrtc, webcam, mediastream

I try to stop the browser webcam permissions indicator by using `track.stop()` like this:

```
myLocalStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    track.stop();
});
```

In most cases this works fine. But if during the session I have switched between different cameras by using `replaceTrack()` it will not work. The browser still shows a running webcam. The code for switching between tracks looks like this:

```
pc.getSenders().map(sender => {
    sender.replaceTrack(myLocalStream.getTracks().find(t => t.kind == sender.track.kind), myLocalStream)
});
```

It looks like after replacing the tracks, the browser has still some references to running tracks, that I don't know how to stop. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue. Did you get it fixed?

Comment: You get tracks using `getUserMedia`, and then you carry the references to them. You can add those tracks to an RTC connection or don't. As long as those tracks are active, regardless of whether they're attached to an RTC connection or not, the camera is active. Apparently you're not keeping track of your tracks appropriately and just try to use the RTC connection to track your tracks, but if you replace tracks, some tracks appear to get lost.

Comment: isn't replaceTrack supposed to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
wecambStream.stop()
```

To stop the cam if not needed

For this:

```js
pc.getSenders().map(sender => {
  sender.replaceTrack(myLocalStream.getTracks().find(t => t.kind == sender.track.kind), myLocalStream)
  myLocalStream.stop()
});
```